# MS Visual Studio 2010 Setup freezes on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, freeze, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to install MS Visual Studio 2010 (I'd prefer a newer version but I'm stuck to this version for other reasons) on a 64B machine with Windows 10. The install wizard hangs up when trying to perform SetVSSCTarget (s. picture) (note: the I/O device error message pops up after ~90 minutes of freezing, so I guess it is just a follow-up error.
[image]
After searching the internet I found the advice to install Process Monitor which I did. I filtered for "setup.exe" and what I noticed is the repeating pattern of the Registry Key "HKLM....\KnownClasses"--> "Name not found" (s. picture).[image]

The pattern you can see repeats like 30 times before the error message pops up. Any idea how to solve this?